How to replicate HTTP server sending TCP packet with flags PSH, [ACK,] FIN? (C/C++ sockets programming)
I've noticed when I benchmark Nginx using WRK, WRK only uses 20% of my total (16t) CPU power using 6 threads (but not 100% usage for each thread, which is why it's only 20%).
I've created my own little multithreaded HTTP server, but when I benchmark that with WRK using the same number of threads, same exact parameters, etc, it uses 40% of CPU and has half the throughput.
Doing some network analysis using Wireshark I found out that Nginx sends the HTTP response with the TCP flags ACK, PSH, FIN, this is what makes the client terminate right after with FIN so I don't have to.
What I have done all this time is shutdown(fd, SHUT_WR), but this creates a separate packet which seems to mess with WRK performance and its CPU usage.
Is there any way using SOCK_STREAM (not SOCK_RAW since Nginx does not use this) to replicate sending an ACK PSH FIN packet? Of course the ACK is automatically generated/determined based on the protocol, but PSH is caused by send(...), but is there a way to do SEND and SHUTDOWN or PSH and FIN at the same time in C/C++?
I've also tried setting TCP_CORK to 1 which didn't work. And trying to figure out how to use MSG_FIN, I tried adding it to the flags of send(...) even though it's not mention in the man pages of "send", but I tried it anyways.
I have now tried shutdown() -> send() as well as send() -> close(). This didn't work.

Are you using the same OS for all your programs?  Which OS, in case it's a matter of OS TCP stack tuning settings?

Run the good server under strace to see the syscalls. Perhaps also ltrace to see the library calls. Are you simulating a DOS attack? It is highly unlikely that TCP flags alone would cause such a performance difference under normal HTTP load.

Try simply close()'ing the socket without calling shutdown(). The default behavior is to send any unsent data before releasing resources, so the system may include a FIN on the last packet.

Hey, I run Debian 12.

I will look into strace, thank you.
I'm not simulating a DoS attack, I would just use SOCK_RAW if that was the case, I'm just using WRK to benchmark and compare the performance of my HTTP servers.
You can see it causes issues because there's a huge delay between the HTTP request and the FIN packet. This causes under-utilization of my multithreaded HTTP server, it's only at about 70%, while Nginx is at 100%.
You can try my old source code yourself and see the problem.
link
I have tried send -> close(). I have also tried shutdown() -> send().

Just a thought: Have you looked at the Nginx source code?

@UlrichEckhardt Yes, many times, searching for keywords to try to find out what it does, but it's like 300 files with probably hundreds of thousands of lines of code and none of my searches has panned out.

Found the answer using strace. I set TCP_CORK wrongly, and I may have to disable TCP_CORK afterwards, at least that's what Nginx does.
Here's the code I used to solve the issue (sending PSH FIN in one go):
setsockopt(event->data.fd, SOL_TCP, TCP_CORK, &enable, sizeof(int));
send(event->data.fd, response.c_str(), response.size(), MSG_NOSIGNAL);
shutdown(event->data.fd, SHUT_WR);
setsockopt(event->data.fd, SOL_TCP, TCP_CORK, &disable, sizeof(int));

This indeed did not solve the WRK performance issue like one commenter said, but it did the thing I asked about in the question.
I am now on the way to figure out the performance issue - namely by capturing WRK packets instead of a single Apache Bench packet I noticed what Nginx also does is use Connection: keep-alive to reuse the connection when there's many inbound connections, and that's what I believe now is the right course of action to optimize for many inbound connections including better WRK results.
